# using group by in IEnumerable result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I have a query like below :

```
 IEnumerable<qryTable1> templates = from t in db.qryTable1
                                           where (t.GID == 1&&
                                           t.RID == 4 && t.CID == "user")
                                           select t;
```

Let say, Above query returns following result:

```
TId GId RId CID
1    1   1   a
1    1   2   a
2    1   1   a
2    1   2   a
3    1   1   a
3    1   2   a
```

Now I want to get result from the above query like below:(removing RId column so that result have duplicate entries having only TId,GId,CID and then group the result by TId).

```
TId GId  CID
1    1    a
2    1    a
3    1    a
```

Also , I want to get the desired output in template object only.It means result should be in '`IEnumerable<qryTable1>`' object.

Comment: If you're not running an aggregate on the group by, isn't this then a `distinct` query?

Comment: I have edited the question at bottom.. please see

Comment: What value do you want for `RId` if you want `qryTable1` entities?

Comment: it can be null or zero. I just need the above desired result. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinct = db.qryTable1.Select(r => new {Tid = r.TId, GId = r.GId, CId = r.CId})
    .Distinct();
```